# Simple geolocation fails in Firefox

Tags: firefox, geolocation

I've got a very simple geolocation test script ([live test](http://www.qmds.info/geolocatetest.php); code below) - this works fine in Chrome, but not Firefox (35) where it consistently fires the `geoError()` function (regardless of the value of `timeout`). Chrome `alert`s the latitude almost instantly.  Other sites requiring geolocation (e.g. [traintimes.org.uk](http://www.traintimes.org.uk/live)) do work reliably in Firefox. What else do I need to do make Firefox play nicely?!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#rungl").click(function() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        geoSuccess, 
        geoError, 
        { maximumAge: 1, timeout: 5000 }
    ); 
  });
});
function geoSuccess(p) { alert(p.coords.latitude); }
function geoError() { alert("oh no :( "); }
</script>
<a href="#" id="rungl">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine when I test it in Firefox.

Comment: @Quentin hmm, that's interesting. I suppose you don't have any ideas what's wrong then?